# how to Myapp directly from your photos app?

Tags: ios, iphone, share

`If i open photos and press the share button share action sheet is opens` ,like this[image]

I want to add my app to this list .

i know it is silly question but i dont know .

any help is appreciated ... thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try something? Did you face any particular problem you can't solve? It's easier and more helpful (for you and future readers) if you show us your work.

Comment: I want for iOS 6 and 7 also.

Comment: If you want to add details, it's better to edit your question than commenting.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Share Extensions Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ShareSheet.html). It's iOS 8 feature so will work only in devices having iOS 8+ versions. You can refer this [tutorial](https://github.com/seviu/share-extension-ios-tutorial) also